# Weighted array based on user input

Tags: php, arrays

I am attempting to allow a user to create an array of index's which are then added to an array with a percentage associated with it. Here is an example:

**EX1**

```
$pages[] = array('index1.php','25');
$pages[] = array('index2.php','25');
$pages[] = array('index3.php','50');
```

or

**EX2**

```
$pages[] = array('index1.php','25');
$pages[] = array('index2.php','75');
```

or even

**EX3**

```
$pages[] = array('index1.php','25');
$pages[] = array('index2.php','25');
$pages[] = array('index3.php','25');
$pages[] = array('index4.php','25');
```

I would like to then create a file with the following contents:

**OUTPUT EX1**

```
index1.php
index2.php
index3.php
index3.php
```

**OUTPUT EX2**

```
index1.php
index2.php
index2.php
index2.php
```

**OUTPUT EX3**

```
index1.php
index2.php
index3.php
index4.php
```

Would I just take the sum of $page[][1] and divide by the number of items in the array?

Comment: How does the algorithm know that you want 4 items in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the minimum number, then just divide it by that, then use str_repeat. (I don't know what's the better way.). Sample Code:

```
$pages[] = array('index1.php','25');
$pages[] = array('index2.php','25');
$pages[] = array('index3.php','25');
$pages[] = array('index4.php','25');

$min = min(array_map(function($weight){
    return $weight[1];
}, $pages));

foreach($pages as $page) {
    echo str_repeat($page[0] . '<br/>', $page[1] / $min);
}
```

Comment: @HydraIO if you want to just put it in a file. just use `file_put_contents` (with permission of course)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind redundancy, just list the file the number of times given by the weight.
For example, you would list index1.php (25/25) times (1), and index3.php (50/25) times (2).

Answer (score 0):

Actually i will not agree with answer, let's say you have

```
$pages[] = array('index1.php','10');
$pages[] = array('index2.php','20');
$pages[] = array('index3.php','40');
$pages[] = array('index4.php','35');
```

Then your output will be:

```
index1.php
index2.php
index2.php
index3.php
index3.php
index3.php
index3.php
index4.php
index4.php
index4.php
```

And this output is wrong. As you see we have `index4` three times here.

To compute correct values you should use greatest common divisor. For example:

```
/*
* function gcd()
* 
* returns greatest common divisor
* between two numbers
* tested against gmp_gcd()
*/
function gcd($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == 0 || $b == 0)
        return abs( max(abs($a), abs($b)) );

    $r = $a % $b;
    return ($r != 0) ?
        gcd($b, $r) :
        abs($b);
}

/*
* function gcd_array()
* 
* gets greatest common divisor among
* an array of numbers
*/
function gcd_array($array, $a = 0)
{
    $b = array_pop($array);
    return ($b === null) ?
        (int)$a :
        gcd_array($array, gcd($a, $b));
}

$array = [10,20,40,35];
$result = gcd_array($array);

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++)
{
  echo $array[$i] / $result;
  echo "\r\n";
}
```

In this case output will be:

```
2 4 8 7
```

(index1 - 2 times, index2 - 4 times, index 3 - 8 times, index4 - 7 times)

and on my opinion this is correct.